# Installation problem with Tensorflow

Tags: python, 16.10

I installed Tensorflow and it worked well so far. However, it displays the following content when I execute my code

```
2017-05-07 12:35:10.449884: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-07 12:35:10.449909: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-07 12:35:10.449919: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-07 12:35:10.449927: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-07 12:35:10.449934: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

I tried many different solution, but it did not work. There is a [solution with bazel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41293077/395857), but I do not use this app I think. How could I fix this problem?

---

```
┌─╼ [~]
└────╼ python3 test.py
2017-05-07 13:23:04.148596: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-07 13:23:04.148624: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-07 13:23:04.148629: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-07 13:23:04.148633: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-05-07 13:23:04.148637: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
Tensor("add:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
5
┌─╼ [~]
└────╼ export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=3
┌─╼ [~]
└────╼ python3 test.py
Tensor("add:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
5
```

However, if I close the terminal and open it again, I will get the same error. How could make the great solution `export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=3` permanent?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question has been posted on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42262984/395857). You can ignore these warnings. If they annoy you, you can mask them with `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'`, e.g.:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
print('TensorFlow version: {0}'.format(tf.__version__))
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

Comment: I know I could  execute `export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL = '3'`, but it seems temporary. How could I make this change permanent?

Comment: @DavidHilbert [How to compile Tensorflow with SSE4.2 and AVX instructions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41293077/395857)

Comment: I know that question, but it did not work, because I did not install tensorflow with bazel and a workspace.

Comment: Your solution worked, but I need to make it permanent.

Comment: I have indicated that bazel did not work. You could see it in my question.

Comment: I use vim, so could I modify the `.vimrc` file so that it works.

Comment: @DavidHilbert sorry I didn't realize that my link was bazel only. To compile TensorFlow people typically use bazel, and it looks like the warning messages can only be removed by recompiling (maybe in more recent nightly builds? I haven't tried recently).

Comment: Yes, but why using `bazel` while it is not necessary?

Comment: My question is simple here : How could I make your solution, i.e.  `export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL =  3` permanent?

Comment: @DavidHilbert [How can I permanently add a key to os.environ?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10262180/395857) and [Is it possible to set an environment variable from Python permanently?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17657905/395857) might give some idea. I haven't explored that direction as in my case I had to ensure the code was cross platform, and subsequently preferred to avoid operating system independent solutions.